# How to Create a function that takes two numbers as arguments (num, length) and returns an array of multiples of num up to length?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I need to create a function that takes two numbers as arguments (num, length) and returns an array of multiples of num up to the length.
So far, i have this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program {
  public static int[] arrayOfMultiples(int num, int length) {
    final int LIMIT = length, MULTIPLE = num;
    
    int[] list = new int[LIMIT];
    for (int index = 0; index < LIMIT; index++)
        
            list[index] = (MULTIPLE *2);
    
    return list;
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is your *specific* question? Does the result differ from what you expected? What did you expect, and what do you actually get?

Comment: *Curious:* Why did you assign the parameters to local variables, instead of just using the parameters directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your right side is not changing, so try something like

```
list[index] = ((index + 1) * num);
```

The multiplication by `2` is not needed.  Also as per @Andreas comments, it is clearer just to use the parameters directly

Comment: Question says *"multiples of `num`"*. --- If `num` is 5, that would be 5, 10, 15, 20, ...

Comment: @Andreas You are too quick (I am too slow) - answer has been edited

Comment: But not correctly edited. Closer, but still wrong. 10, 20, 30, ... is not 5, 10, 15, 20, ... Though I do guess you *could* argue that 10, 20, 30, ... are multiples of 5, I doubt that's what the assignment meant for the result to be.

Comment: For example, i want arrayOfMultiples(7, 5) ➞ [7, 14, 21, 28, 35], in which num is 7 and my length is 5;

Comment: @DanH If that's what you want, why did you assign the same value to all positions in the index in the question text? Didn't you think the value of `index` should somehow be involved with the assigned value?

Comment: @Andreas Right, did not consider that.

Comment: @DanH saves a lot of effort if you say what you want in your question.

Comment: I AM SO SORRY!!!! I WAS OVERTHINKING IT. Andreas and Scary Wombat thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using Java 8+ Stream logic:

```java
public static int[] arrayOfMultiples(int num, int length) {
    return IntStream.range(0, length).map(i -> (i + 1) * num).toArray();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfMultiples(7, 5)));
```

*Output*

```
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35]
```